# Displaying specific words in a .txt file using a scanner

Tags: java

I'm stuck and need your help (yes, it's homework), what I'm trying to do is get my code to read the contents in the text file and output the words by specific words. For example I want it to output all words that start with letter "g".

Here's a pseudocode code if I didn't explain that well:

```
BEGIN

Get the initial letter from the user

While there are more entries in the file

Get the next personal name

Get the next surname

Get the next year info

If the surname starts with the initial letter

Output the person name, surname and year info

End while

END
```

So far I've managed to get this done, and now I'm stuck where you output the names correctly. Any help or tutorials will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class PrimeMinisters
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // ask the user for the first letter
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the first letter? ");
        String input = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
        char firstLetter = input.charAt(0);

        // open the data file
        File pmFile = new File ("OZPMS.txt");
        // create a scanner from the file
        Scanner pmInput = new Scanner (pmFile);

        // read one line of data at a time, processing each line
        while(pmInput.hasNext())
        {
            String names = pmInput.next();
            System.out.println(names);
        }

        // be polite and close the file
        pmInput.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is personal name, surname, and yearinfo all on one line?

Comment: Hi Moncadad, yes, each name, surname, and year info is all on one line. Sorry if I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `nextLine()` over `next()`. From this you would then use the `String`'s `startsWith(String stringsequence)` method which returns a boolean to get all the values beginning with the letter of your choice:

```
  while(pmInput.hasNextLine())
        {

            String names = pmInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println(names);
            if(names.startsWith("g")) {
              //the name begins with letter g do whatever
            }
        }
```

You can have a look at more methods for String here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirements state to look at the surname's first letter, it will be easier to  tokenize each line while you read it (while checking to see if the user input is the first letter of the surname). Assuming that the line is in the order that you stated above, the surname will be token #2 (index 1 of the array).

```
public class PrimeMinisters
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            // ask the user for the first letter
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("What is the first letter? ");
            String input = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
            char firstLetter = input.charAt(0);

            // open the data file
            File pmFile = new File ("OZPMS.txt");
            // create a scanner from the file
            Scanner pmInput = new Scanner (pmFile);

            // read one line of data at a time, processing each line
            while(pmInput.hasNextLine())
            {
                String names = pmInput.nextLine();

                // Break line into tokens. This is assuming that there are only
                // 3 strings per line in the following order (personal name, surname, yearinfo)
                //
                String[] info = names.split("\\s"); 

                 // Check 2nd string in line (since you are looking for the first   character in 
                 // the surname and not the personal name.
                 //
                if(info[1].startsWith(input))  
                {
                      System.out.println(info[0] + "\t" + info[1] + "\t" + info[2]);
                }
            }

            // be polite and close the file
            pmInput.close();
        }
    }
```